# OpenCv copyTo() not working

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to apply masking to an image using copyTo() function of openCv, but masking is not working. I still obtain the same image.

When I searched the web, I saw some suggestions like:

-source and destination images must be different,
 -source image must have type CV_8U, 
 -mask image must have type CV_8U, etc.

I tried all of them, but i could not fix the problem. Moreover, at the official OpenCv website, no such restrictions are mentioned.

Here is a part of my code:

```
Mat source; //initialized in some way
Mat mask; // this is also initialized in some way

source.copyTo(source, mask);
```

Comment: from source you copy all pixels that are active in the mask to source. what do you expect to be all the pixels that are inactive in the mask?

Comment: try cv::Mat destination(source.size(), source.type(), cv::Scalar (0,0,0,0)); source.copyTo(destination, mask);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mask should be single channel image with values either `0` or `255`.

```
Mat mask(source.rows, source.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
```

with the above mask image, you should get a blank image in the destination because all the mask values are zero.

And with the following mask, you should be able to get a same destination image as source image because your whole mask image is activated with values `255`.

```
Mat mask(source.rows, source.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(255));
```

And for some other mask for which only few regions of the image contain white pixels, you will get a that regions of your source image in the destination image.